# How to display Author Profile based on Custom field value

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta, user-meta, author

I need to display additional author profile based on Custom Field Value.

I am using native wordpress custom filed declaration. so for my custom field name is

```
$coauthor = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'coauthor', true);
```

and in page I had given Bhargav Joshi to coauthor custom fields, so i need to display Complete author profile with Bhargav Joshi.

How can i show this? It doesn't matter when i want to show inside loop or outside loop.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use meta query.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'coauthor' ) );
```

Later, you can loop through this query.